# Place a comma and a space before every word with a capital letter

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm working with ruby and I'm trying to place a comma and a space before every word with a capital letter apart from the beginning word.

```
str = Taxonomy term Another term One more

puts str.gsub(/\s/, ', ')
```

Output > `Taxonomy, term, Another, term, One, more`

Desired output > `Taxonomy term, Another term, One more`

My regex skills are very rusty so im simply stuck at this stage.

Any idea how to reach my desired output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pattern:

```
\s(?=[A-Z])
```

[DEMO](http://www.rubular.com/r/8FbGiKoXgR)

And your code would be,

```
puts str.gsub(/\s(?=[A-Z])/, ", ")
```

`\s(?=[A-Z])` Spaces which are  followed by an Uppercase letter are matched. Then the matched spaces are replaced  with a comma followed by a space.

Comment: +1 for short and sweet. I'd suggest inserting a boundary `\s(?=\b[A-Z])` So we don't insert in a CamelCase word.

Answer (score 5):

You can capture the capital letter and use it in the replace.

```
str.gsub(/\s(\p{lu})/, ', \1')
```

Using `\p{lu}` will match any Unicode upper case letter.

```
puts "Taxonomy term Another term Ōne ĺess".gsub(/\s(\p{lu})/, ', \1');

Output:
Taxonomy term, Another term, Ōne ĺess
```

Comment: Thank you for understanding that there's more to the world than ASCII.

Answer (score 2):

You better not insert a new space. Use the one that was there.

```
"Taxonomy term Another term One more"
.gsub(/(?=\s+[A-Z])/, ",")
# => => "Taxonomy term, Another term, One more"
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
str.gsub(/\s(?<capital>[A-Z])/, ', \k<capital>')
```

This one will do a named match on the capital char and replace it with comma followed by space and the char again.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you've become emotionally attached to what you tried:

```
str = "Taxonomy term Another term One more"

s = str.gsub(/\s/, ', ')
  #=> "Taxonomy, term, Another, term, One, more"
```

you could `gsub` that:

```
s.gsub(/, ([a-z]+)/,' \1')
  #=> "Taxonomy term, Another term, One more"
```

Putting it together:

```
str.gsub(/\s/, ', ').gsub(/, ([a-z]+)/,' \1')
  #=> "Taxonomy term, Another term, One more"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
puts str.gsub(/\s(?=[A-Z])/, ", ") # => Taxonomy term, Another term, One more
```

Comment: I didn't down vote but (a) no explanation at all (b) this is already covered by other answers (c) this (like almost all the others) is limited to ASCII and that's a shame in 2014.

Answer (score 0):

```
irb(main):001:0> 'Taxonomy term Another term One more'.gsub(/\s+([A-Z])/, ', \1')
=> "Taxonomy term, Another term, One more"
```

Comment: It would benefit the OP and others if you explained the code rather than just posting it and moving on.

Comment: Google will help explaining the ruby's regex syntax much faster.